# Is there anyway to build Couchbase Lite in macCatalyst

Tags: ios, macos, couchbase-lite, mac-catalyst

In Couchbase documentation, I've found that they provide iOS and macOS frameworks, but I want to turn my iPad app into a macOS app using mac Catalyst. Is there any way to do this?

I added both the iOS and macOS framework but Xcode is stating

> "Building for Mac Catalyst, but the linked framework
> 'CouchbaseLiteSwift.framework' was built for macOS. You may need to
> restrict the platforms for which this framework should be linked in
> the target editor, or replace it with an XCFramework that supports
> both platforms."

Comment: Couchbase Lite does not support catalyst as yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why @rajagp didn't post this as the answer.  It *is* the answer:

"Couchbase Lite does not support catalyst as yet."